# How to sort the list of products in infinite scroll in Ionic 6

Tags: sorting, ionic-framework, infinite-scroll

<ion-infinite-scroll threshold="150px" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">

Comment: do you append into the list or sort the list ,

Comment: If it is infinite scroll you will need to do this on the server side. It is like pagination but triggered automatically